# Webscraping with Python: requests.get(param) does not update although param updates

Tags: python, get, python-requests, screen-scraping

I have the following problem: I try to scrape the namecensus website (https://namecensus.com/male_names.htm)
with the following code:

```
for counter in range(0, len(links_male)):
 print("Sleeping for 2 Seconds")
 time.sleep(2)
 print(url)
 html_page=rq.get(url) 

 bs_instance_male=BeautifulSoup(html_page.text,"html.parser")
 print(bs_instance.h1)
 table_entries=bs_instance.select(".datatable > table >tr >td")

 for entry in table_entries: 
    male_firstname_data.append(entry)

 #Update Url 
 counter+=1
 if(counter<len(links_male)):
    url=links_male[counter]
    print(f"URL updating to: {url}")
 else:
    print("Done")
```

This gives the following output: [picture of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFg7X.png)

As you can see it somehow doesnt update the variable html_page although the URL-String is correctly updated?
Can someone explain me why this is the case?
Thanks!!

Comment: You should add your output in code fences(``` ```), not in screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning `bs_instance_male` but printing `bs_instance.h1`, I assume there is the problem. Also, the example you supplied is not a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In order to improve the chances of useful answers, make sure readers can just copy your code and get the same problem as you are getting. The process of making such an example will in most cases make the problem evident before even posting the question.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am new to this!